# boost::asio, spawn and post, how to get the post result

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, boost-asio

As I understand it is possible to use `asio`'s `spawn` and `post` (calling `post` from inside `spawn`) and to obtain the result outside of `asio` context, however I have a difficulty to figure out how to do it. I didn't find any example how to achieve the above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use any way you usually do. Post another task with the result bound, or use a `promise` to get a `future`

Comment: I was thinking about promise/future, it is a solution if you work with multiple threads, but you are quite limited with these `futex` based solutions because of `futex` throughput. In case you work from the same thread and `spaw`ning multiple tasks, is there any other mechanism available which would be lighter? Something like boost::fibers to use here?

Comment: Atomics, or not "spawning".

Comment: I can think of atomics as a way to signal completion, not return meaningful value, am I missing something? if not `spawn`ing then what? just `post`ing?

Comment: If you can atomically switch pointers, you can basically communicate amount of state.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Have to rethink the approach. Thanks for the idea, sehe